# Using ng-if on a parent element depending on src of img

Tags: angularjs

I am showing and image within a  as follows:

```
<div class="logo-wrap" ng-if="fallback=src">
 <img class="logo" ng-src="{{logo_src}}" fallback-src="/app/ci/images/1x1.png"  />
</div>
```

I want to remove the  if my image is using the fallback-src. My fallback-src directive is:

```
 angular.module('myApp').directive('fallbackSrc', function () {
   var fallbackSrc = {
     link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
       iElement.bind('error', function () {
         angular.element(this).attr("src", iAttrs.fallbackSrc);         
       });
     }
   }
   return fallbackSrc;
 });
```

`{{logo_src}}` returns a string of the image URL from an API so it's up to the browser to find the image or throw a 404, so that's why I have a fallbackSRC directive. The issue now is that I want to remove the parent `<div>` (which I need when there is an image) when we are using the fallback-src.

What `ng-if` expression do I need to detect if the img src is using the fallback-src?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your directive uses fallback source when the `logo_src` variable is not available, use

```
<div class="logo-wrap" ng-if="logo_src">
 <img class="logo" ng-src="{{logo_src}}" fallback-src="/app/ci/images/1x1.png"  />
</div>
```

This code means that when `logo_src` is available, the div is rendered.

I think you will need to change your directive to hide the image if src is equal to the value of fallbackSrc. I can't think of a way for the `ngIf` to figure out both the src and the fallbackSrc to do a comparison. The `ngIf` above hides the `logo-wrap` only if there is no value on the `logo-src` variable.

If you want to hide the directive if there is a 404 error, your html code will need to change a bit like so...

```
<div class="logo-wrap">
 <img class="logo" ng-src="{{logo_src}}" fallback-src="/app/ci/images/1x1.png"  />
</div>
```

and your directive...

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('fallbackSrc', function () {
  var fallbackSrc = {
    link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
      // Remember to remove the class hidden if the image src changes.
      iElement.bind('error', function () {
        angular.element(this).attr("src", iAttrs.fallbackSrc).parent().toggleClass("hidden", true);         
      });
    }
  }
   return fallbackSrc;
});
```

css for hidden class...

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

I'll admit, this solution doesn't solve the problem in the way you want, i.e. doesn't remove the div but I believe it achieves the same result.

Comment: The issue here is that although fallback-src directive changes the <img> src to a different src (1x1.png) the logo_src still exists as a string and hence the <div> still appears.

Comment: You can set your directive to add a class to the image. This class can have a style of `display: none;`

Comment: I've updated the answer to explain the solution a bit more. I have not run the code so it may have some syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks Caleb. This works when there is no image. But when I navigate to another page my "hide" class still exists - until I hit refresh.

Comment: If the image `src` changes when you navigate to another page, then you need to watch for those changes and remove the class.